# Excel 2016 on Windows 10 high CPU usage when idling

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

When I open an empty Excel file, CPU usage immediately goes to 25%. When I close Excel, Task Manager still shows the process running, and the only way to shut it down completely is to kill the process. I noticed that Excel is trying to make calls to mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com every second when it's running. I am currently blocking calls to this domain. I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/ags9m3/high_cpu_usage_in_ms_word_whitelist/) that someone who had the same issue was able to fix it by whitelisting this domain. I would rather stop Excel from trying to connect. As far as I am aware I have disabled all telemetry options everywhere in Windows 10. There is no reason Excel should have to send anything to Microsoft, since this is not Excel 365, and I do not want it to check for updates either. Does anyone have an idea how to stop these calls and why they are being made?

Comment: I'd like to suggest you go to `File > Options > Trust Center > Crust Center Settings > Privacy Options, clear any enabled box under Privacy Options`. Besides, have you tried the methods in "[Disable data collection for the agent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/manage-the-privacy-of-data-monitored-by-telemetry-in-office#disable-data-collection-for-the-agent)"?

Comment: @Emily, I have tried both of your suggestions. Unfortunately, neither worked.

Comment: Emm, there is not too much information from Microsoft documents to explain the relationship between URL and Excel on Windows. What I found on the Internet is to add it as a whitelist, just like Gilgamoth replied in this post "[Excel 2016 (And Outlook 2016) Constant CPU Usage](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2147138-excel-2016-and-outlook-2016-constant-cpu-usage)".

Comment: well, the idea is to not let these calls go through, because I don't know what is being sent, and it does not need to send anything.